# What prevents a natural fibers rope from untwisting when it is elongated?

Tags: friction

I don't understand why a rope doesn't untwist when an attempt is made to increase its length. It seems counter-intuitive to me, because untwisting would allow the rope to increase its length, but in practice it does not untwist.

Do the braids spiral-like shape and the friction between the braids prevents this from happening ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at http://usscouts.org/scoutcraft/BoyScoutRopemaking.pdf

When you make a rope the individual fibres are twisted before you combine them into the rope. It's the "untwisting" force of the individual fibres that locks them together in a rope. You're quite correct that if you try to make a rope without twisting the fibres your rope will just fall to bits.